# Swift 3 replace words in String, checking against values in array

Tags: arrays, swift, string

Let's say I have a variable of type String holding a single String. In this string, there are 1 or more words. I also have an array of Strings. I want to check the String against the array, looking for, and replacing words found in the array.

For instance, the word "able" is in the array. The word "able" is also in the String variable. I want the word able replaced with the "+" character.

I've tried like this:

```
//stopWords = array of Strings / keywords = String variable
for words in stopWords {
        keywordsFormatted = keywords.replacingOccurrences(of: words, with: "+", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
}
```

and that doesn't change anything. I've also tried in a while loop, and a few other ways that I don't even care to recall right now lol. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
let stopWords = ["red", "green", "blue"]
let keywords = "The sky is blue not green"
```

let's create a set

```
let stopWordsSet = Set(stopWords)
```

and finally let's solve the problem

```
let result = keywords
    .components(separatedBy: " ")
    .map { stopWordsSet.contains($0) ? "+" : $0 }
    .joined(separator: " ")
```

Oh... and lets test it

```
print(result) // The sky is + not +
```

> Please note this solution is **case sensitive**. Furthermore it will not work is words in keywords are not delimited by spaces. E.g. `"The sky is blue, not green"` will not work properly because of the `,`.

Addendum from **Adrian**:

If you want to update the textField, just use `didSet`, like so:

```
var keywords = "The sky is blue not green" {
    didSet {
        // if keywords is not empty, set the myTextField.text to keywords
        if !keywords.characters.isEmpty {
            myTextField.text = keywords
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hopeful but that's not working either. I forgot to mention keywords is the value of a text field set like

`var keywords: String = ""`
`keywords = searchField.text!`

edit, I would expect the output to be delimited by spaces and am testing it as such.

Comment: @froggomad I added a little to the answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks the last bit wasn't necessary. To be clear, I was assigning values to keyword from the text field. not the other way around... I'm not sure why it didn't appear to be reformatting keywords but it is!